# User confirm registration by email with FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FOSUserBundle, set everything according to the symfony documentation. However, after setting up the confirmation email User registration, it does not work and does not send any error message. What can I do? Is there anything else I should do? Thank you.

this file below are the settings of my config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  gmail 
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyBundle\Entity\User


    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            from_email:
                address: myaccount@gmail.com
                sender_name: The name
```

this file below are the settings of my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:

    mailer_user: myaccount@gmail.com
    mailer_password: xxxx
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Comment: Have you checked symfony's dev log?

Comment: What does mean "does not work"?
Do you not receiving E-Mails?
Is the Server trying to send an email ( in e.g. mail.log )?

Comment: @cilefen yes, but there is nothing in there. Do you have managed configure the mail confirmation?

Comment: @develth I don't receiving e-mail. I do not know what is happening. I received no error message or warning.

Comment: @lackner maybe the mail was sent from symfony2 / PHP and so no error message is shown, because it succeeded. I think its a Mailtransport issue. What is your dev environment? can you send via swiftmailer a mail with this settings?

Comment: @develth Well I believe that the registration page should be redirected, and it did not. I was developing with the sublime and I am now installing netbeans, and I put the code in a free web server.

Comment: @lackner: check the symfony2 profiler, last 10 requests and get on the POST on register. Is there an 302? and on the flashes an success?

Comment: Do you say to check in the log file?

Comment: nope, the symfony profiler.

Comment: @develth But if I do it on localhost, generate an error, because I do not have a smt server in here.